# Camera position for 2D graph window in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using a cubic bezier curve as a pure math object in order to generate a series of vertices for a geometry.  But I would like also to simultaneously see the curve I'm working with, not just the vertex points I derive from it.

So I made a new div containing a new scene, renderer, camera, etc, and I placed my curve there, so far so good. I put a 1x1 gridHelper in there, too, as background graph paper.  I had to rotate it to the xy plane, and translate it (.5,.5) to get it to sync up with my graphed line.  Very nice.

But -- and here's my ignorance showing -- I'm having a devil of a time positioning the camera to display a simple, square, 00-to-11 graph that fills my div straight on.

I've tried lookat and all kinds of positions and rotations, but I can't seem to figure out a starting position / camera settings combo that just works.

Any advice would be well-appreciated.

Comment: As an option, you can use [`THREE.OrthographicCamera()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the value of camera.left right top and bottom.. and adjust them. Also play with camera.zoom .. between those 2 settings you should be able to position/scale to whatever you want. You may need to set camera.aspect or similar as well to match ratio of viewport width / height. If you can't figure it out.. post a codepen or a jsfiddle.